# Set date value into datetimepicker bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm wish to set the date value into the [datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) using jQuery based on the value got from the datetimepicker (datetimepicker1) and duration (input_duration) in days. Any idea how to do it? Here are my code:

HTML

```
<label for="label_duration" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Duration</label>
<div class="col-sm-2">                          
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_duration" name="input_duration" placeholder="Days" required/>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
    <label for="label_duration" id="lblStartDate" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Start Date</label>
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" name="startdate" id="startdate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"  required/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
    <label for="label_duration" id="lblEndDate"  class="col-sm-2 control-label">End Date</label>
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" name="enddate" id="enddate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" required/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            viewMode: 'years',
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        });

        $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
            viewMode: 'years',
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This will change up the date modal and update your date time picker widget

```
    var newDate = moment(); // Can be a moment object, JS date object or a  valid date string
    $('#datetimepicker-1').data("DateTimePicker").date(newDate);
```